# TYPO3: powermail2 and double optin link with time limit possible? (3 days)

Tags: typo3, newsletter, typo3-6.2.x, powermail

is it possible to set a time limit for activation link in TYPO3 powermail2 extension when double-optin in set? For example: After a time limit of 3 days, the user data should be deleted and the activation with this link isn't possible any more. I need this for a newsletter registration, based on german protection of privacy law.

Hope someone has a idea and can help me :)

Answer (score 1):

No, not out of the box in powermail.